# Casting an object which class is the same

Tags: java, list, casting

I'm doing a query search on a database, that returns a list. The List is filled with variables type Object. I do an query.get(0).getClass() and it returns (something).WorkbookMappingClass. But the thing is I have to Cast that object to an WorkbookMapping object. But its giving me an I/O error(maybe its because of the Exception being practically global.)

Here's the code:

```
WorkbookMapping wk;
List query = ses.createQuery("FROM Workbook").list();
System.out.println("Class: "+query.get(query.size()).getClass());//return ...WorkbookMapping
wk =(WorkbookMapping)query.get(query.size());
```

Anybody have an idea?

Comment: An IO error?  An erroneous cast would cause a `ClassCastException`; so the problem is not with your cast.  What is the **exact** stack trace you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last element of the *List* will be the *query.size()-1* as long as the Lists are 0-based like arrays. So *query.get(query.size())* returns null in your example.

Comment: Thanks alot :D One more question. Inside of wk I have a list of objects, and each of those objects has another list. If I want to access the size of the list, I have to do something like this right?

Comment: Yes. But if you want to know the exact number of objects on all levels of hierarchy below some certain level, you will have to iterate through your lists to call size() on each element. Or use composite design pattern.

Comment: wk.list.get(i).list.size();

Answer (score 1):

```
WorkbookMapping wk;
List query = ses.createQuery("FROM Workbook").list();
System.out.println("Class: "+query.get(query.size()).getClass());//return    ...WorkbookMapping
Object obj = query.get(query.size() - 1)
if(obj instanceof WorkbookMapping) {
    wk =(WorkbookMapping);
}
```

Irrespective of that, as `Charlesworth` suggested, you should have either a `ClassCastException` or `ArrayIndexOfBoudsException` (as you are accessing with `query.size()`)